# Custom Metadata Types Relationship

Tags: apex, metadata, custom-metadata

I want to create a Custom Metadata Types field using the Metadata Relationship that links this custom metadata type to Profile object, is that even possible ? if yes can you please show me how would I do

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. The Metadata Relationship to Profile would be an Entity Relationship and as you can see from a sample row taken from `Manage Records` that `Profile` is not available

[image]

Field SObjectType is defined as a field in the CMDT like this:

[image]